# Make game canvas high res (retina)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, retina, game-maker

The goal is to make a game canvas high res / retina.

I'm working with a software called Gamemaker and I want to make this canvas high res / retina. Though I have no real idea how to implant this.

Here are two links who explain the problem very clearly
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/ 
and
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/

This is the code the html5 page uses to launch the game:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480">
<script type="text/javascript" src="html5game/GameMaker_HTML.js?AHMYB=1445354237"></script>
```

The game's javascript file is unreadable.

How do I achieve making the whole javascript canvas high res / retina?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using GameMaker for the past 4 years and this year I am using in my Internship class and we had wondered the same thing and to my knowledge and our out come no answers when we searched, I do not believe you can implement this your self... This is something YoYo Games would have to add into their program as this would be getting into file that you may not know how to edit safely or that you may not have access to... 
I hope this kinda helped!
But to put an up side to this, since 4k screens are coming out and becoming more widely used that means they will implement this soon and that means you can upload a quality game even better than the Retina display puts out XD.